# Delete Archive Logs only from Flashrecovery Area after Backup

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i am working with an Oracle 11G Database. The Database is in the archivelog modus with multiplexing in two destinations. the fist destination is the flashrecoveryarea and the second a network device. 
After a fullbackup i want to delete all archivelogs in the flashrecovery area but keep the logs for 7 days in the network device.
For the second destination i am using the following statement:

```
"delete archivelog until time 'sysdate -7' like 'Path\arc%'"
```

But if i create the statement for the first destination i got the error

```
delete archivelog until time 'sysdate' like "Path\%\%"
```

i got the error message

```
specification does not match any archived log in the repository
```

It would be nice if someone has a hin for me

Greetings